# Speed up NPM install in Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

We use the standard practices of not including node_modules in version control. However, when moving through the CI/CD pipeline, we have to reinstall NPM dependencies in several places and it makes everything very slow.

Is there a way to somehow cache NPM dependencies with Docker? I searched Google "docker cache npm dependencies" and the first hit from 2014 yielded a dead link.

Nothing else of much value came up.

One solution is to include node_modules in version control, but I think that would be a huge mistake. I think caching the dependencies somehow would be the best option.

Here is the Dockerfile as is:

```
FROM node:6

COPY . .  # copy all files, but node_modules does not exist ( => gitignored)

RUN npm install --no-optional --only=production > /dev/null 2>&1
RUN npm install -g bower  > /dev/null 2>&1
RUN bower install --config.interactive=false --allow-root > /dev/null 2>&1

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/root/cdt/run.sh"]
```

Here is one possible solution, but I can't quite figure out how it works:

=> http://bitjudo.com/blog/2014/03/13/building-efficient-dockerfiles-node-dot-js/

Comment: How does your Dockerfile look like?

Comment: A possible solution is to use the [`-v`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only) option in the Docker command line to map `~/.npm` to `~/.npm` in the container. This way on subsequent executions it uses an already populated cache. However, the improvement is not spectacular, it still needs ages to resolve the dependencies.

Comment: I just added my Dockerfile, thanks

Comment: I added an answer, I think this might be the best solution, although there may be some supplemental solutions on top of that.

Comment: Unless you go out of your way to change it, most docker files run with the root user. So you might run into permission issues in ~/.npm with that method.

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3124 for more info, and work arounds

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This method works like magic:

https://blog.playmoweb.com/speed-up-your-builds-with-docker-cache-bfed14c051bf

Docker has a special way of caching things for you, and apparently it's best to use the inborn caching ability.

Cannot say I completely understand how it works, but it does work.

If you follow this pattern, it will work for you:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:5.6.0
WORKDIR /src

# Expose the port 3000
EXPOSE 3000

# Set the default command to run when a container starts
CMD ["node", "server.js"]

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /src
RUN npm install

# Copy your code in the docker image
COPY . /src
```

Comment: At the `COPY package.json /src` instruction, docker checks if the package.json file has changed. If it has changed it will rerun the `RUN` command below. it works but if you frequently change package.json it's a mess. Perhaps using shared volumes might install the modules faster

Comment: I agree, if you change package.json frequently, it doesn't help anyone

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using yarn instead of npm which is way faster? Yarn does parallel package installations

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/compare/

Comment: yeah I was thinking about that, but then I would have to install Yarn first

Comment: Woudn't yarn add alot more benefits than using npm ? I think its worth it if you can use it with a base image. If not then im not sure. I am a newb when it comes to docker.

Comment: Yeah it might, but I don't think Yarn will come part as the base image, so I would have to do npm install -g yarn, then run yarn. I am also not that certain yarn is all that faster? Are there any stats on how much faster?

Comment: There is also npm-yarn-benchmark that can benchmark performance between both

Comment: thanks, I added an answer, this appears to be the best way to do it - the secret is that Docker has its own way of doing caching and it's different than you would expect.

Comment: Would like to mention that the new *npm 5* is faster or comparable in speed to *yarn*. Since yarn has to be installed in docker, it might be useful to just use node version 8+ instead, this comes with npm 5 pre-installed.

Comment: Yarn should be safer because it is MITM proof, not sure if npm already worked on it, but last time I checked they didn't (about 2021)

And yarn should come preinstalled in the latest node image

Answer (score 5):

Additional tricks for collection:
In square brackets is the relative time saved in my case

- If cache-based solution is not an option, manually creating `node_modules` prior install speeds up `npm@8` in `alpine` docker (source: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3208#issuecomment-1002990902). [-80sec]

```
RUN mkdir node_modules
```

- Skipping security audit on docker. [-30sec]

```
RUN npm ci --no-audit
```

- Using other package managers like pnpm, even with additional install it's still faster.

```
RUN npm install -g pnpm
RUN pnpm install
```

Answer (score 2):

Increasing CPU for Docker solved my problem.

For docker-compose.yml (if you use):

```
version: '3'
services:
  your-service:
    image: your-image
    cpus: 2 # this change is enough for me
```

If you use Dockerfile directly:

```
docker run --cpus=2 -d your-image-name
```

Additionally, it's my Dockerfile for my Nuxt app. It would be helpful for someone:

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution doesn't work for me, my code had been already like that.

Update the command from `npm install` to `npm ci`. `ci` here means clean and install. When I updated it, my installing in Docker finished in 6 minutes which can not be finished before even spent 30 more minutes.